# How to make fastlane use specific version of OpenSSL

Tags: ios, openssl, rubygems, fastlane

I'm getting

> Connection reset by peer

when running `fastlane get_provisioning_profile` . My theory is that my fastlane installation is not using the right openssl version.

I have openssl installed via brew install openssl.

`bundle exec openssl version` returns `1.0.2s 28 May 2019`

`openssl version` returns `1.0.2s 28 May 2019`

But when I run `bundle exec fastlane env`, it uses `1.0.2g 1 Mar 2016`. 
I'm using `fastlane 2.127`

Is there a way to tell fastlane to use the one installed by brew or better use 1.1.1?

Complete env here: https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/15051

> ~/.bash_profile

```
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
```

Comment: What does `bundle exec fastlane env` return?

Comment: OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016 is that what you mean? The whole env is here: https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/15051

Comment: Nah, you indicated that you ran "fastlane env". I am asking for "bundle exec fastlane env" which might be different.

Comment: Yes I actually meant `bundle exec fastlane env`. description updated

Comment: @Ted You might want to give OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext::DEFAULT_PARAMS[:ssl_version] = :TLSv1_2 in your config a try. Worked for us for many random timeouts.

Comment: Hi thanks for the suggestion! May I know which config file exactly?